# CI-HMVC template layout

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I am starting to use CodeIgniter and HMVC. I can build modules with no problem - all day long.

But now I'm wanting to have a simple HTML template to insert my modules into. Are there any good tutorials on doing this?

I'm just building a single domain site that users can login and use assigned modules on the template.

Answer (score 1):

There are two good ones I know of.

http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html

and ...

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template